# Taking a snapshot of ReplaySubject<T> buffer

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I have a large ReplaySubject that allows subscribers to receive the replay buffer and future notifications as normal. In addition, I would like to be able to take a "snapshot"
of the current buffer and return that as a list synchronously, without having to subscribe.

Is there a way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just subscribe, receive the items, then unsubscribe?

```
public static List<T> Snapshot<T>(ReplaySubject<T> subject)
{
    List<T> snapshot = new List<T>();
    using (subject.Subscribe(item => snapshot.Add(item))
    {
        // Deliberately empty; subscribing will add everything to the list.
    }
    return snapshot;
}
```

That's assuming that subscribing to a `ReplaySubject<T>` invokes the element handler synchronously, of course. You'd want to check that, but that's what I'd expect.

You should also consider whether you want to handle errors / completion somehow.

Comment: I was about to describe that this is wrong because subject might not be completed yet, but it's actually the *only* way to do it (and isn't wrong). Clever!  That being said, I'd probably copy the source from ReplaySubject and add an explicit method to do this

Comment: Thanks guys, this works fine, I just assumed there might be something else I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

**ONLY** because @PaulBetts said there's only one way to do it :)

note: I don't recommend this way; Use Skeet's method and you'll thank yourself later.

So the magic of a `ReplaySubject<T>` all has to do with the fact it queues up any values it receives via `OnNext` on an internal `Queue<TimeInterval<T>>`. So we can write a wrapper that fiddles around inside the private details of the replay subject to get that info:

```
public class FixedReplaySubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    private ReplaySubject<T> _inner;
    private Func<Queue<TimeInterval<T>>> _snapshotGetter;

    public FixedReplaySubject(ReplaySubject<T> source)
    {
        _inner = source;
        var expr = Expression.Lambda(
            typeof(Func<Queue<TimeInterval<T>>>), 
            Expression.Field(
                Expression.Constant(source), 
                source.GetType()
                    .GetField("_queue", BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)));
        _snapshotGetter = (Func<Queue<TimeInterval<T>>>)expr.Compile();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TimeInterval<T>> Snapshot()
    {
        return _snapshotGetter();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        return _inner.Subscribe(observer);
    }
    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        _inner.OnNext(value);
    }
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        _inner.OnCompleted();
    }
    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        _inner.OnError(error);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Test rig:

```
void Main()
{
    var src = new ReplaySubject<int>();
    src.OnNext(1);
    src.OnNext(2);
    src.OnNext(3);
    src.OnNext(4);
    src.OnNext(5);
    src.OnNext(6);
    var heh = new FixedReplaySubject<int>(src);
    heh.Snapshot().Dump();
}
```

Result:
(`TimeInterval<T>` is just value + time it came in)

```
1 00:00:00.0010265 
2 00:00:00.0010278 
3 00:00:00.0010278 
4 00:00:00.0010282 
5 00:00:00.0010282 
6 00:00:00.0010286
```