# SynchronousBuffer Extension Method for IObservable<T>

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need a Buffer method that doesn't buffer on time or on a certain condition.
It should behave similar to this snapshot method:

[Taking a snapshot of ReplaySubject<T> buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185863/taking-a-snapshot-of-replaysubjectt-buffer)

However it should not take a single snapshot, it should buffer when synchronous changes occur ond provide them as IObservable<IList<T>>.

I think there should be an almost simple solution as this Snapshot method, but I can't get my head around how to really solve this. (Note: The snapshot mehtod also works good for queries over multiple subjects)

**Here is a test Method:**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task SyncBufferTest()
    {
        var i1 = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);
        var i2 = new BehaviorSubject<int>(4);
        var sum = i1.CombineLatest(i2, (i1Value, i2Value) => i1Value + i2Value);
        var listAsync = sum.SynchronousBuffer().Select(buf => buf.Last()).ToList().RunAsync(new CancellationToken());

        Action syncChange1 = () =>
        {
            i1.OnNext(2);
            i2.OnNext(5);
            i1.OnNext(7);
        };

        Action syncChange2 = () =>
        {
            i1.OnNext(1);
            i2.OnNext(1);
        };

        Action syncChange3 = () =>
        {
            i1.OnNext(3);
            i1.OnCompleted();
            i2.OnCompleted();
        };


        Task.Run(syncChange1)
            .ContinueWith(t => syncChange2())
            .ContinueWith(t => syncChange3());

        var list = await listAsync;

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new List<int> { 5, 12, 2, 4 }, list.ToList());
    }
```

**Background:**

I am working on an architecture concept with a reactive data layer as the base of the application. The whole data layer consists of Subjects (as a "talking" data layer). In a single transaction multiple of these Subjects are changed. I have many Observables in a higher layer of my application that are queries to multiple of these Subjects. So I need this SynchronousBuffer to handle synchronous changes to all of these subjects in all of these queries to not get notified multiple times.

Comment: Identical question ?? If so, you should delete one.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60560566/synchronousbuffer-extension-method-for-iobservablet

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the other

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a reactive solution, it's always easier if you model your inputs as observables. In this case:

```
var i1 = new BehaviorSubject<int>(1);
var i2 = new BehaviorSubject<int>(4);
var sum = i1.CombineLatest(i2, (i1Value, i2Value) => i1Value + i2Value);
Action syncChange1 = () =>
{
    i1.OnNext(2);
    i2.OnNext(5);
    i1.OnNext(7);
};

Action syncChange2 = () =>
{
    i1.OnNext(1);
    i2.OnNext(1);
};

Action syncChange3 = () =>
{
    i1.OnNext(3);
    i1.OnCompleted();
    i2.OnCompleted();
};
IObservable<Action> actions = new Action[] { syncChange1, syncChange2, syncChange3 }.ToObservable();
```

Same as the question, just we're structuring our Actions as an observable series of changes. Now, magic can happen:

```
var openWindow = new Subject<int>();
var closeWindow = new Subject<int>();
var gatedActions = actions
    .Select((a, i) => new Action(() => {
        openWindow.OnNext(i);
        a();
        closeWindow.OnNext(i);
    }));
```

Now we have windows defined, which can easily be passed into `.Buffer()` or `.Window()`.

```
// alternative to window. Not used.
var buffer = sum.Buffer(openWindow, i => closeWindow.Where(cwi => cwi == i)); 

var listAsync = sum
    .Window(openWindow, i => closeWindow.Where(cwi => cwi == i))
    .SelectMany(w => w.TakeLast(1))
    .ToList()
    .RunAsync(new CancellationToken());

gatedActions.Subscribe(a => a(), () => { openWindow.OnCompleted(); closeWindow.OnCompleted(); });

var list = await listAsync; //output is {12, 2, 4}. The starting 5 can be worked in with a .Merge() or something.
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer. But I can't use the actions for the solution. The changes are happening from outside (see Background). Thats why I want to buffer synchronous changes.

Comment: The actions aren’t that relevant, the open/close windows are. “Synchronous changes” is pretty meaningless. If you can find someway to model what those synchronous changes as an observable, then you’re fine.

Comment: So you mean there is no sensible way to detect synchronous changes and the best solution would be to provide the user of the data layer a mechanism to open and close a transaction when modifying the subjects?!

Comment: Most likely. How are you defining synchronous changes?

Comment: I define synchronous changes as multiple calls to different Subjects.OnNext, that happen inside a single control flow by a task or thread or some other concept I don't have control over.

Comment: Rx is a powerful set of functions which generally take in two types of input: time, and data in observable form. “Synchronous Changes” is neither of those two things. If you want to use Rx functions, figure out a way to model your changes as data in observable form.

Comment: Yeah I know that. And I don't want to provide it as an input. I want it to be figured out implicitly. Like Skeet's snapshot function gets the first batch of synchronous notifications.

Comment: I posted another answer using time. Skeet's answer has nothing to do with your problem, which is detecting what you're terming 'synchronous changes'. The only thing that may be helpful in detecting that is maybe adding a ThreadId.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209169/discussion-between-felix-keil-and-shlomo).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to try to define a time window within which you consider changes to be synchronous:

```
var synchronounsWindow = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
var actions = new Action[] {syncChange1, syncChange2, syncChange3};
IObservable<Unit> allChanges = Observable.Merge(
    i1.Select(_ => Unit.Default), 
    i2.Select(_ => Unit.Default)
);
```

Once we have a time window, you can apply the same windowing/buffering techniques as the other answer.

```
var buffer = sum.Buffer(allChanges.Throttle(synchronounsWindow)); //alternative to window if you like

IList<int> list = null;
var listAsync = sum
    .Window(allChanges.Throttle(synchronounsWindow))
    .SelectMany(w => w.TakeLast(1))
    .ToList()
    .Subscribe(l => { list = l;});

foreach (var a in actions)
{
    a();
    await Task.Delay(synchronounsWindow);
}
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new List<int> { 12, 2, 4 }, list.ToList()); // again, skipping 5
```